# Where is the .tex equievelant .pdf files located in ubuntu?

Tags: pdf, tex-core, ubuntu, find

I have tried `find . -name "*.pdf"` in various folders where I would initially think that the `pdf` files would be exported to. Both `/usr/share/texlive` and `/usr/share/textstudio`
does not contain either my `tex` files nor their `pdf` exports. I have run pdflatex command, and read somewhere they should be located where the `tex` files are. But I cannot find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you'll get by running e.g. `pdflatex novel.tex` will show up in the same directory where `novel.tex` is located (unless something went wrong and no PDF file was written), normally called `novel.pdf`. Usually you'll set up a directory in your `$HOME` for each (set of) documents you work on. E.g., one your your hopefully prize-winning novel, one for letters, one for your regular column on Ubuntu, Gnus and Gnats, ... and work there.

The directories you cite contain the packages that make up your TeX distribution, do not mess with them unless you *do* know what you are doing. And if you do know, you'll know to leave them well alone.